# How to get Table A all data with tables B only rows which matches with Table A

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables I want to select all the records which presents in table location with cardId 2, and if a location is mapped in location_card table then name of the location

Its doable by making separate query and then joining them in script, but I wanna get in single query. I tried with below query but that dint work.

```
SELECT `cl`.`locationId`, `cl`.`cardId`, `l`.`name`
FROM (`locations` as l)
JOIN `location_cards` as cl ON `l`.`cardId` = `cl`.`cardId`
WHERE `l`.`id` =  '2'



location_cards
+---+-------------+-------+
|id | locationId  |cardId |
+---+-------------+-------+
| 1 | 1           |   1   |
| 2 | 1           |   2   |
| 3 | 3           |   2   | 
+---+-------------+-------+


locations
+---+-------------+-------+
|id | name        |cardId |
+---+-------------+-------+
| 1 | some        |   1   |
| 2 | pla         |   2   |
| 3 | sdsdffsdf   |   2   | 
+---+-------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change to a `LEFT JOIN` but it also appears your `WHERE` clause is using the wrong filter:

```
select c.locationid,
  c.cardid,
  l.name
from locations l
left join location_cards c
  on l.cardid = c.cardid
where l.cardid = 2
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c80b/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try change your `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` and order of joins.

```
SELECT `cl`.`locationId`, `cl`.`cardId`, `l`.`name`
FROM `location_cards` as cl
left JOIN `locations` as l   ON `l`.`cardId` = `cl`.`cardId`
WHERE `l`.`id` =  '2'
```